# Catch IllegalStateException and stop my Gradle/Groovy build and print a message?

Tags: groovy, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have this:

```
task buildNative(type: Exec) {
    try {
        if(System.getenv().NDK_HOME != null) {
            def ndkBuild = new File(System.getenv().NDK_HOME, 'ndk-build')
            workingDir "jni"
            executable ndkBuild
        } else {
            doLast {
                println 'Reason: NDK_HOME not set...'
            }
        }
    } catch(IllegalStateException){
        println 'Reason: NDK_HOME not set...'
    }
}
```

And since NDK_HOME is not set in my environemnt I'd like to stop my build and print a message. How can I do this?

If I run gradle assembleRelease with --stacktrace I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: execCommand == null!
```

If I run with gradle assembleRelease I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':primavista-android-reloaded:buildNative'.
> execCommand == null!
```

I'd like:

```
Reason: NDK_HOME not set...
```

And from within Android Studio it does not run at all, even if I have the correct NDK_HOME. With the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':primavista-android-reloaded:buildNative'.
> execCommand == null!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
task buildNative(type: Exec) {
    if (System.getenv('NDK_HOME') != null) {
        def ndkBuild = new File(System.getenv('NDK_HOME'), 'ndk-build')
        workingDir "jni"
        executable ndkBuild
    } else {
        throw new GradleException('Reason: NDK_HOME not set...')
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why you first check for `DK_HOME` rather than `NDK_HOME`.

Comment: Because I know DK_HOME does not exists in my environment, it's just a test. It does not stop.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what the problem is. Please improve your question.

Comment: :primavista-android-reloaded:buildNative FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':primavista-android-reloaded:buildNative'.
> execCommand == null!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: That likely means that `NDK_BUILD` *is* set. You can easily verify that by adding some `println`s inside the if-statement. Perhaps you are running into some other problem.

Comment: I found the problem, your code was correct. It was my try/catch block... Thanks!